# cant run dd command on android device

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, dd, android

The main objective is to send a splited file to an android and join it back up with a .sh script, the file is splited to 5MB parts but its total size is unknown (trying to make an universal script), I've splited the file and transferred the file parts and the script to a dir inside the android device and ran the .sh with adb shell sh script.sh.
every thing is is ok but the dd command which wont accept a variable

```
file="$(ls /data/local/tmp/ | grep -i --include="*.tul" tul)"
echo file is "$file" 
name="${file%.*}"
echo short name is "$name"
tmp="${file: -3}";
num=${tmp//[!0-9]/}
echo number of files is "$num"
N="${name}.part1"
dd if="/data/local/tmp/$"${name}.part1"" of=/data/local/tmp/cust bs=1024 count=5120
i=1
while [ $i -le $num ]; do
dd if="/data/local/tmp/$"${name}.part1""$i"" of="/data/local/tmp/cust" bs=1024 count=5120 seek="$((($i-1)*5120))"
let i=i+1
done
echo DONE
exit
```

the output normally is that the end of the name cuts the beginning and I get dd if No such file or directory
meaning

```
/data/local/new_file.part1
becomes something like .part1local/new_file
```

while in command lind adb shell it works OK

```
adb shell
 >dd if="/data/local/tmp/$"${name}.part1"" of=/data/local/tmp/cust bs=1024 count=5120
```

$file is an index file that has the parts name and total number of them generated by the split code (in java)

edit:

```
dd if=/data/local/tmp/"$name".part"$i" of=/data/local/tmp/cust bs=1024 count=5120 seek="$((($i-1)*5120))"
```

working in command line (adb shell) but when running the .sh file I get

```
.part2: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Remove the double quotes and the extra $ from the command and it will work normal: `dd if=/data/local/tmp/${name}.part1 ...`

Comment: Also not working, even if I try

Comment: @ott Also not working, even if I try [code] dd if=/data/local"$name".part"$i" [/code] I get .part2: No such file or directory $i being an index number

Answer (score 1):

You're using Bash-like syntax and operators (`$(command)`, `${...//}`), but running it by `sh`, which on Android is not Bash by default.

Comment: So what would be the Wright way?

Comment: @GurmanEduard **If** that's the problem, rewrite with portable `sh` syntax or run Bash if it's available (most likely not). You can experiment if you're running Linux by feeding your script to a lighter shell like `dash` or `ash`/`busybox sh`

Comment: Also not working, even if I try [code] dd if=/data/local"$name".part"$i" [/code] I get .part2: No such file or directory $i being an index number

Comment: @GurmanEduard but how are you setting the value of `$file`? The original script doesn't set it in a portable way

Comment: Every thing up to the dd command works and the I get error as posted in the edited part of the question,if I echo the a var with the dd if string it looks OK